# Error in simple html dom

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

When I start my code in WampServer I get this error:

---

```
Warning: file_get_contents(http://www.fragrantica.com/designers/A-Perfume-
Organic.html): failed to open stream: A connection attempt failed because the 
connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established 
connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. in 
F:\wamp\www\atr\fragantica\simple_html_dom.php on line 76
```

---

I test some things before and it works for 3's of my URLs but after that give me 
this error!.I use my wamp local server with latest version of simple_html_dom version.My code is a little complicate but can be read!...

```
function connect($furl,$fsname){
$fup=fopen("$furl","r"); // open file of urls for read 
$fname=fopen("$fsname","r"); // open file of file's names for set name
$i=0;
while(!feof($fup)){
    $url=trim(fgets($fup)); // read lines from furl file
    $name=trim(fgets($fname));
    $fdoc=fopen("$name.txt","w"); // make a new file for put contents in it
    $html=file_get_html("$url"); // read contents from favurites html page
    foreach($html->find("div.perfumeslist p") as $tag){
        foreach($tag->find("a") as $alink){
            $perlink="http://www.fragrantica.com".$alink->href;
            fwrite($fdoc,"##PERFUME_LINK:##".$perlink."\n"."\n");
        }
        foreach($tag->find("img") as $im){
            fwrite($fdoc,"##THUMB_SRC:##".$im->src."\n");
        }
        foreach($tag->find("span.mtext") as $sp){
            fwrite($fdoc,"##SEX:##".$sp->innertext."\n");
        }
        $perfume=file_get_html("$perlink");
        foreach($perfume->find("div") as $disc){
            if(strcmp($disc->itemprop,"description")===0){
                fwrite($fdoc,"##DESCRIPTION:##".$disc->innertext."\n");
            }
        }
        foreach($perfume->find("div#mainpicbox img") as $per){
            $pic=$per->src;
            fwrite($fdoc,"##MAINPICURL:##".$pic."\n");
        }
        foreach($html->find("div") as $tag){
            if(strcmp($tag->style,"width: 230px; float: left; text-align: center; clear: left;")===0){
                foreach($tag->find("p") as $notes){
                    fwrite($fdoc,"##NOTES:##".$notes->innertext."\n"."\n");
                }
            }

        }


    fwrite($fdoc,"___________________________________________________________________"."\n");
}
        fclose($fdoc);
    }
    fclose($fup);
    fclose($fname);
}
```

About my code:

in this function I read two files :one for name of my text file and another 
for URLs files.first reads line by line from these files and it goes until 
 to end of file then use the file_get_html and get tags and attributes to
 to get it's link source and inner texts ...

Comment: try with curl operation

Comment: I need this code fast! I don't have enough time to learn curl lib. @Tushar

Comment: The URL is broken into two lines just here or in your code too?

Comment: Just here! I test URL directly and it's work! @chris85

Answer (score 1):

```
$ch = curl_init();
$timeout = 20;
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);

$fileContents = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

// Create a DOM object
$html = new simple_html_dom();
// Load HTML from a string
$html->load($fileContents);
```

Try with this, I have not execute this so I am not sure

Comment: This error occurred!`Maximum execution time of 120 seconds exceeded` what am I do? @Tushar

Comment: just updated answer with
$timeout = 20;
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);

Please check

Comment: can you also check maximum execution time in your php.ini file

Comment: or you can use as follow
You'll have to set it to zero. Zero means the script can run forever. Add the following at the start of your script:

ini_set('max_execution_time', 0); or set particular time

Comment: I put this value 500.but i got this error again!I don't know what am i do.

Comment: When I run this code it works correctly but it gets a lot time and don't put put text files.I think i have some trouble with memory or wampserver